# JupyterLab overwrite filebrowser contents with custom drive

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am trying to create my own Filebrowser extension that uses IRODS instead of local file browsing. I am basing my work off an existing extension found here.

https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-github

my code is here

https://github.com/towicode/jupyterlab_irods

For the most part copying over the code has worked well... Except one thing. I can't figure out how to replace the default filebrowser listings. In the github extension it lists your github repository as if they were local file/folders; that is the idea I am going for.

However, in my extension, I cannot seem to replace the default listings or even have my drive.get() code to be executed at all. Instead it just lists my local file listings.

I haven't found much documentation for jupyterlab extensions so I am a little dumbstruct. I've reviewed the differences between the code in my repository and the other repository and I feel like I am not missing any major parts (although apparently I am). I'm hoping someone can briefly explain to me the process of how I can accomplish replacing where Jupyterlab gets the results for file listings.

Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: I have a theory I'm going to look into. in my drive.ts I don't set a .getname function, and it looks like you add a drive by name. Maybe that's what is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Check out the commit "ILS Working...kinda".

Basically you need to make sure to fill out the name of the drive, otherwise it seems like it uses a default name or something. Not too sure.